# Which resolution to work with in photoshop for websites?

Tags: web, dreamweaver, photoshop

I just need to create a single page website in Photoshop, the display has to be optimized for PC, tablet, phone etc. Which resolution do I work in to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create several designs that are suited for those devices that you expect to be typical. Decisions depend on the product you are selling and the personae of the typical clients.

Since you are doing a single page app the exact height is not as critical but you still need to design to several base heights for the various devices and get the developer to just display more background to fit.

The screen size for PCs is increasing but usually a good bet is to go for either 1280 or 1400 wide. For tablets and phones there is an ever increasing set of form factors. Note that many tablets can display higher than a typical PC, its your call how high you want to support. Google for advice or [read here.](http://99designs.com/designer-blog/2012/12/03/responsive-web-design-key-tips-and-approaches/)

So designers choose to do the smallest form factor first to identify the key information and content and then create the next width up etcetera.

I usually design for at least three screen sizes (as defined by research of my clients expected users) and set some guidelines on how the various elements degrade as width in/decreases so the developer knows how to setup his CSS correctly and hopefully support new devices that come to market without a redesign.